# Generalized linear mixed-effects model and Interaction of Continuous and Dummy Categorical variable Standardised vs Non-Standardised?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme

I have run a GLMER on some data and I have 3 random variables (Year,Patient and Group) and I have an interaction that exists between a continuous(days) and dummy categorical variable (0-Disease absent and 1-Disease present). But when I have not standardised the continuous I get a different outcome,I was expecting this in terms of estimates changing but there is also a change in terms of P value of the disease variable when the continuous variable is standardised vs when it is not.
Both converge and have the same AIC and BIC so which is better to use for interpretation. If I use the non-standardised varible I get a very high estimate for disease and the P value is significant but the estimate drops and also becomes not significant for disease when the continuous variable is standardised.
I am assuming the standardised output is what I interpret but I am not sure?

Code

```
Model <- glmer(Test ~ (1|Group) + (1|Year) + (1|Patient.ID) +
                   Days*Disease, 
                   data=DF1, family = "binomial")
```

Non-standardised output;

```
 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2399.9   2445.4  -1192.9   2385.9     4945 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3797 -0.2916 -0.2183 -0.1685  8.5600 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Patient.ID (Intercept) 0.04472  0.2115  
 Group      (Intercept) 0.21043  0.4587  
 Year       (Intercept) 0.39095  0.6253  


Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.521091   0.397524  -3.826 0.000130 ***
Days         -0.022762   0.004669  -4.876 1.09e-06 ***
Disease       4.273912   1.292344   3.307 0.000943 ***
Days:Disease -0.076111   0.031543  -2.413 0.015824 *  

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Days   Disease
Days        -0.530              
Disease     -0.112  0.157       
Days:Diseas  0.092 -0.141 -0.964
```

Standardised Ouput;

```
 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2399.9   2445.4  -1192.9   2385.9     4945 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3797 -0.2916 -0.2183 -0.1685  8.5601 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Patient.ID (Intercept) 0.04471  0.2114  
 Group      (Intercept) 0.21044  0.4587  
 Year       (Intercept) 0.39093  0.6252  


Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        -2.65754    0.33783  -7.866 3.65e-15 ***
Stand.Days         -0.31035    0.06366  -4.875 1.09e-06 ***
Disease             0.47383    0.47393   1.000    0.317    
Stand.Days:Disease -1.03778    0.43075  -2.409    0.016 *  


Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Stnd.D Diseas
Stand.Days   0.066              
Disease     -0.028 -0.040       
Stnd.Dys:Ds  0.011 -0.141  0.693
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the interaction remains consistent across the two models, as it should. The problem is with the main effects. The main effects for variables that are also interacted in a model have a localized rather than marginal interpretation. In the unstandardized model, the disease main-effect is the effect of disease when days is equal to zero. This is unlikely to be of any interest. Similarly, the days main-effect is the effect if days when disease is equal to zero. Also unlikely to be of interest. In the standardized model, the main effects have a more meaningful interpretation given that the data are centered. Now each main effect is the effect at the mean of the other variable that is part of the interaction. For example, in the standardized model, the disease main effect is the standardized effect of disease at the mean of days. This is why it is recommended to center variables if you are creating interactions. Centered variables will give you a model that is consistent with your standardized model but with unstandardized coefficients.